# Vue server side interpolation doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering

This is my first venture into Vue.js server-side, and here I'm stuck. I'm using Node 12.16.3 and TypeScript.

```
const Vue = require('vue');
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer();

export class VueService {

  public createInstance(): Promise<string> {

    const app = new Vue({
        template: `<div>Here is {{ whatever }}</div>`
    });

    const context = {
        whatever: 'something'
    }

    return renderer.renderToString(app, context);
  }
}
```

This is supposed to return `Here is something` but all I get is `Here is`. The HTML string is the following:

```
<div data-server-rendered="true">Here is </div>
```

I'm following this guide:
https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#using-a-page-template

There's a warning on the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "whatever" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, 
by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

There's nothing about this in the guide... what now?

Of course if I put `whatever: 'something'` into the `data` property of the `Vue` object, it works. But what's the point of the context then?

Comment: context are used to pass data to main template

Comment: All the guide says is "Given the following template:" which I assume is the one passed to the Vue object. Isn't it?

Comment: in createRenderer function if you pass any template then context is useful [See docs](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#using-a-page-template)

Comment: Yes, and this is exactly what I did. If you scroll down to the next section, it provides an example where `title` is being passed through the context and appears as page title. I just did that, and it doesn't work either. So what is `context` then, and how is it different from `data`? Where is it passed?

Comment: data is used only for its rendering component only but to pass data to its parent or wrapped html template we can use context 
also if you can post your full example so the question will be more clear

Comment: So context is used to pass data to the client-side, to the template that encapsulates the server-rendered document?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219393/discussion-between-vishnu-bhadoriya-and-tamas-polgar).